# Error in spark submit java.lang.OutOfMemoryError while reading 5-6 GB of text file using wholetextfile method

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have 5 files each file containing size as

```
   File1=~500KB
   File2=~1MB
   File3=~1GB
   File4=~6GB
   File5=~1GB
```

And I am  using wholetextfile to read all 5 files. Each file has different number of columns.

```
     *val data = sc.wholeTextFiles("..........Path......./*")
```

On Further analysis I found that my code is not working after below line..Any suggestion on how to use mappartition in this case

```
     val files = data.map { case (filename, content) => filename}
     files.collect.foreach( filename => {
     ..../Performing some operations/...
     })*
```

So when I try to submit this code on server then it gives error as  *java.lang.OutOfMemoryError*
Code works fine when I remove 6GB file from the source path. So only issue with the file with big size.
I am using below spark submit code..

```
    *spark-submit --class myClassName \
    --master yarn-client --conf spark.executor.extraJavaOptions="- 
           Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties" \
   --conf spark.driver.extraJavaOptions="-Dlog4j.configuration=...FilePath.../log4j.properties" \
   --files ...FilePath.../log4j.properties --num-executors 4 --executor-cores 4 \
   --executor-memory 10g --driver-memory 5g --conf "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=409" \
   --conf "spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=409" .................JarFilePath.jar*
```

**Spark Version:1.6.0
Scala Version: 2.10.5**

Comment: Ask for even more (eg. 20-30g) memory? Or can the problem working set be reduced?

Comment: Still not working

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you use *wholeTextFile* instead of *textFile* because "Each file has different number of columns.". (Note: *textFile* have a smaller memory requirement in this case, so you can have this code working without increasing --executor-memory). Basically the schema is not aligned between the files. If your end result is schema independent (i.e. having the same number of columns), then you can implement a preprocessing layer by starting a spark job on each file with *textFile* that outputs the desired content with the same content, number of columns.

Otherwise you can filter out the large files and start separate spark jobs on those to split them up to smaller ones. That way you will fit in memory.